# Getting meta data related to a Visual Workflow From Rest Api

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

i want to retrieve list of Visual Workflow in VisualForce page.i dont want to use SOAP api because its very bulky in size(Metadata Service class size).Is there any soql query method or rest api method for getting list of Visual WorkFlow available in salesforce or soap api is the only method

we can get list of Apexclass in soql query using 
`Select Id From ApexClass` is same type of soql query exist for visual work flows ??
.Plz guideline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the objects that represent a Flow have key prefixes starting at [300](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#300) and going through to 31v.

E.g.

- 300 InteractionDefinition
- 301 InteractionDefinitionVersion
- 308 InteractionCondition

None of these currently (Spring 14 / v30.0) appear to be accessible via the Partner API, the tooling API, or directly in Apex. They don't appear in the sObjects returned by a REST GET to `/services/data/v30.0/sobjects` or `/services/data/v30.0/tooling/sobjects`.

In Apex you can see the SObjectType, but that is about it.

```
Schema.SObjectType r = Id.valueOf('300100000000000').getSObjectType();
System.debug(r); // Debugs as InteractionDefinition
```

I'd say the Metadata API is currently your best option (e.g. via [SFDC workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)):

[image: Flows in the Metadata API]